# Get sum of all numbers in range

Tags: python, range

I have a range from 1 to 5.
Each number in that range gets squared.

```
for x in range(1, 5 + 1):
  x = x ** 2
  print(x)
```

Doing this, gives me:
1, 4, 9, 16, 25.

That is perfect, but how do I then request the sum of the new numbers in the range so that they equal 55?

Comment: math to the rescue! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number

Comment: Thanks!
I had it, I made 2 mistakes, I was using sum as a variable and I had a typo.

Comment: @Sinfamy You don't even have to iterate. There is a formula to find the answer. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Accumulate the sum:

```
>>> total = 0
>>> for x in range(1, 5+1):
...     total += x ** 2
...
>>> total
55
```

More preferably, using [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
>>> sum(x**2 for x in range(1, 5+1))
55
```

Answer (score 4):

alternative [square pyramidal number solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number) (as suggested by M4rtini):

```
(2*(5**3) + 3*(5**2) + 5)/6
```

or for general n:

```
def square_pyramid(x):
    return (2*(x**3) + 3*(x**2) + x)/6
```

Comment: You don't need the parentheses around the exponentiation.

Comment: @Tim - of course that's true, I just find it to be more readable, plus I find that a liberal use of parentheses rather than depending on operator precedence can prevent some  tricky bugs.

Answer (score 1):

```
total = 0
for x in range(1, 5 + 1):
    x = x ** 2
    total = total + x
    print(x)
print total
```

The above should help you out. You want to be storing the sum as you calculate X into another variable. You can then use the sum further along in your program.

Comment: Ah, good point. Sorry, I have not used python in a very long time. (response to comment about not using sum as a variable name because it hides built in function called sum)

Answer (score 1):

One line:

```
sum(x**2 for x in xrange(1,6))
```

Comment: The `[ ]` isn't necessary, without them it's a generator expression that works equally well.